# LOW pins on ESP32 during flashing and normal boot

Tags: esp8266

I use ESP8266 in my project. Now I'm going to change to ESP32 ([datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_datasheet_en.pdf)). For ESP8266, I know GPIO4 & GPIO5 are always LOW, during the flashing or normal boot.
Using these pins can simplify the logic of my board. What pins are always LOW on ESP32?

Comment: Please read its datasheet and what does Expressif say about it ?

Comment: It seems not very easy to find out. At least, I couldn't!

Comment: Yeah, but you should add that infomation to the question.

Comment: The answer would be a couple of numbers, what kind of info do I need to add!?

Comment: Your effort, link to various datasheets ?

Comment: This information is readily found via a web search for "esp32 boot pins" . Perhaps the issue is that it was not clear that the reserved purpose of these pins is to select the boot mode and related options.